# How to host flask API on Google Colab notebook for testing purpose?

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I am trying to host flask API on google colab notebook, here is the google colab notebook link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15TElc4G0Fp5hNRMhdWh7NDxnqCTTHBcN?usp=sharing

I do get ngrok URL, but opening this URL says

**Tunnel 11deff2aa4d8.ngrok.io not found**

Can someone confirm if there is something changed in Google colab settings?
Regards,

```js
!pip install flask-ngrok

from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)   #starts ngrok when the app is run
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Running Flask on Google Colab!</h1>"
  
app.run()
```

Comment: I can confirm that suddenly I'm having the same problem. Seems they have changed something on Colab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tunnel not found error Pyngrok streamlit collab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966425/tunnel-not-found-error-pyngrok-streamlit-collab)